# Is there a difference from alignment with the fuselage between J79 and Spey engine versions used in the F4?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

Is there a difference between the J79 and Spey engine versions used in the F4 Phantom in terms of alignment with the fuselage? It looks to me like the Spey nozzles are pointing downward.

Comment: Are you asking if the engines are different from each other (eg J79 vs Spey) or if the engines are different from the design standard (eg J79 in the F-4 vs J79 in the F-104)?

Comment: I'm asking if the engines are different from each other  J79 vs Spey.

Comment: Oh, childhood memories! I used to build scale models as a kid, and always wondered about the weird alignment of the Phantom's nozzles. Not sure which version I had built then though.